# How to identify ERC 20 swaps using ehterscan API

Tags: erc-20, etherscan, uniswap, swaps

Hi I would want to identify ERC 20 swaps for a certain ETH address using etherscan API.
At their site method column shows if it's a swap.[image: Etherscan token transfers]

But the json of the response doesn't include a method field, and I haven't been able to find any swap clue.

Thanks!

Comment: Please include the json response you are getting and also the request

Comment: Thanks. This is the request: https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=tokentx&address=0x4e5fab20b7b83c6f557b20c820883eab0a0b343b&page=1&offset=100&startblock=0&endblock=27025780&sort=asc&apikey=<MY_KEY>

Comment: RESPONSE: {"status":"1","message":"OK","result":[{"blockNumber":"13028378","timeStamp":"1629012374","hash":"0x06...","nonce":"4","blockHash":"0xd...b","from":"0xe....36","contractAddress":"0xed04915c23f00a313a544955524eb7dbd823143d","to":"0x4e5fab20b7b83c6f557b20c820883eab0a0b343b","value":"500000000","tokenName":"Alchemy","tokenSymbol":"ACH","tokenDecimal":"8","transactionIndex":"44","gas":"6682921","gasPrice":"33199999999","gasUsed":"5990048","cumulativeGasUsed":"8539402","input":"deprecated","confirmations":"4626287"},....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Etherscan Screenshot]

In the logs, I can see there's a Swap event emitted by the [Uniswap contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0xf5c4bbd3b9f4ad7a5dec1422e888aa5c8e467c21#code).

```
    event Swap(
        address indexed sender,
        uint amount0In,
        uint amount1In,
        uint amount0Out,
        uint amount1Out,
        address indexed to
    );
```

You're not able to access this through the API?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I thought the etherscan response could contain that info. But if I have to access through UNI API I'll do.

Comment: You're welcome.